# "Create Shortcut" Checkbox

Tags: wix, windows-installer, shortcut

I'm using the WiX Tool to create an installer.

I need the installer to make it optional, when creating Start Menu and Desktop shortcuts.

Something like: *[   ] Do you want to create a start menu shortcut?*

Is that possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  The general idea is to make the shortcut component be conditional on a property, then customize your UI to connect a checkbox to that property.

All of this is described (though not for your specific example) in the [Wix Tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial), an insightful read.  But here are some more specific code samples for your case:

### Add a Property

Create a property that you can hook the checkbox up to.  In your .wxs file, add a `Property` to store the value in.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product ...>
    <Property Id="INSTALLSHORTCUT" />
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

### Add a Condition

Add a `Condition` to the component that installs the shortcut, so it's conditional on the value of your new `INSTALLSHORTCUT` property.

```
<Component Id="ProgramFilesShortcut" Guid="*">
  <Condition>INSTALLSHORTCUT</Condition>
  <Shortcut Id="ProductShortcut" ... />
</Component>
```

### Add the Checkbox

You need to customize a dialog to add a checkbox to the UI and hook it up to the `INSTALLSHORTCUT` property. I won't go into all the details here, but there's a good tutorial here:  [User Interface Revisited](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited)

You'll need to download the wix source tree to get the .wxs files for the UI you are using.  To add the checkbox to the `InstallDir` dialog in the `WixUI_InstallDir` UI, for example, you would download `WixUI_InstallDir.wxs` and `InstallDirDlg.wxs`.  Add them to your Wix project and rename them (e.g., `Custom_InstallDir.wxs` and `Custom_InstallDirDlg.wxs`).

Edit `Custom_InstallDirDlg.wxs` to add your checkbox.  Give the `<Dialog>` a new `Id` too:

```
<Wix ...>
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="InstallDirAndOptionalShortcutDlg" ...>
        <Control Id="InstallShortcutCheckbox" Type="CheckBox" 
                 X="20" Y="140" Width="200" Height="17" 
                 Property="INSTALLSHORTCUT" CheckBoxValue="1" 
                 Text="Do you want to create a start menu shortcut?" />
       </Dialog>
     </UI>
   </Fragment>
 </Wix>
```

Edit `Custom_InstallDir.wxs` to use the customized `InstallDirAndOptionalShortcut` dialog:

```
<Wix ...>
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="Custom_InstallDir">

      ** Search & Replace all "InstallDirDlg" with "InstallDirAndOptionalShortcut" **

    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Finally, reference your customized UI in your main .wxs file:

```
<Wix ...>
  ...
  <UIRef Id="Custom_InstallDir" />
  ...
</Wix>
```

Comment: `<Property Id="INSTALLSHORTCUT"  Secure="yes"/>` Secure must be set to yes in order for this property to be accessed by the condition.

Comment: Good answer, but a little bit incomplete. To get it run I **additionally** had to **do this in the component** snippet: **(1)** Add a `Directory` property to `<Component>`, e.g. `<Component ... Directory="APPLICATIONDIR">` **(2)** The `<ShortCut>` needs these properties: `<Shortcut ... Advertise="no" Target="[#MyApp.exe]" />` (note: it's a file ID in "Target") **(3)** Add a dummy registry entry to the component like `<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="desktop icon = 1" KeyPath="yes" />` to avoid WiX errors. **(4)** See Felix's comment

Answer (score -5):

On the checkbox click event or on the next button click you can call an custom action to create shortcuts.

Comment: I'm trying to use a checkbox for the user to chose to install a file (or not).  I followed these steps and it did not work.    Is there something missing in the capture of the check box interaction (like a publish command or something)?